# Remove the tableview gray background color while swipe to right in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scrollview, swipe

I have a tableview dynamic prototype custom tableview cells.
My tableview cell color is white and the background of tableview is also white.
I want swipe to right delete feature for my tableviewcell, and with custom tableviewrowaction
I have implemented the same in my app with custom tableviewrowaction which is working fine but the only problem is when I swipe right the cell bounces and there is a gray background color behind the cell. I have removed the backgroundview, changed the color of cell and tableview but still when I swipe the cell , I can see the background color as gray.
Following is the code written to display the custom tableview delete row action

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .default, title: "") { (action, indexPath) in
        let cell =  self.tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CardInfoSwipeCell
        cell?.deleteAction(action)

    }

    deleteAction.setIcon(iconImage: UIImage(named: "delete")!, backColor: UIColor.white, cellHeight: 100.0, iconSizePercentage: 0.79)

    return [deleteAction]
}
```

Following is the code to set the image on tableviewrowaction

```
extension UITableViewRowAction {

    func setIcon(iconImage: UIImage, backColor: UIColor, cellHeight: CGFloat, iconSizePercentage: CGFloat)
    {
        let iconHeight = cellHeight * iconSizePercentage
        let margin = (cellHeight - iconHeight) / 2 as CGFloat

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: cellHeight, height: cellHeight), false, 0)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        backColor.setFill()
        context!.fill(CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:cellHeight, height:cellHeight))

        iconImage.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: margin, width: iconHeight - 10, height: iconHeight - 4))

        let actionImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(patternImage: actionImage!)
    }
}
```

Please find the attached screenshot where a gray background gets displayed behind
[image: Swipe Screenshot]

Is there any way to disable the tableview dragging bounce so that it should not be dragged beyond a certain point.

Comment: Did you tried to change cell background color to clear?

Comment: @ivarun Yes i have tried that but still the same issue exist

Answer (score 3):

I tried setting the background color to `.clear` but that did not work. This workaround gets the job done.

`action.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.001)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use this library  https://github.com/SwipeCellKit/SwipeCellKit allows you to place icons on the `UITableViewRowAction`

> [TableView] Setting a pattern color as backgroundColor of UITableViewRowAction is no longer supported.

[image: Swipeable UITableViewCell/UICollectionViewCell based on the stock Mail.app, implemented in Swift.]

Comment: i have designed my tableviewrowaction in the same way mentioned in this library but the problem is i want tableviewrowaction with rounded edges so i have added an entire image to row action which is with rounded edges

Answer (score 0):

To disable the tableview dragging bounce you can use the following method -

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

    let delete = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, sourceView, completionHandler) in

       // Code to perform delete action
        completionHandler(true);
    }

    let swipeAction = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions:[delete])
    swipeAction.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false // This is the line which disables full swipe
    return swipeAction

}
```

Comment: Have tried this solution as well, but this dont work with custom tableview row action as while i drag the cell i can see number of buttons with my custom image